# jQuery: how do I select no elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, identity, empty-list

I want to create a jQuery selection that is guaranteed to have no DOM nodes in it. Obviously, I can do this with various hacks, like selecting an id that I know does not exist, but that sucks. How do I do this idiomatically?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @PhonicUK for the same reason you frequently use `0` or `""` literals in your code; they are monoid identities that form your base case. In particular, I want to `.add()` together an array of jQuery objects; this requires me to construct an initial empty value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do this -

```
var empty = $();
```

This creates an empty jQuery object:

Comment: Aha! Searched everywhere for it.

Answer (score 0):

I never been in this situation but you could use this.

```
$("<div></div>");
```

or

```
var empty = {};

console.log($(empty).attr("id"));

console.log($(empty).text());

console.log($(empty));
```

Output:

```
undefined

""

{"0": {}, "add": function (e,t){var n=typeof e=="string"?v(e,t):v.makeA..................
```